# Newbie question: openai.ChatCompletion.create not seeing endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-openai

Newbie going through a tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/paths/develop-ai-solutions-azure-openai/.  Copied the neccessary bits to the .env file:

```
AZURE_OAI_ENDPOINT=https://XXXXXXXXX.openai.azure.com/
AZURE_OAI_KEY=6abaeXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
AZURE_OAI_MODEL=gpt-35-turbo
```

Doing some sample code but got this error:

```
dsur [ ~/azure-openai/Labfiles/02-nlp-azure-openai/Python ]$ python test-openai-model.py 
Sending request for summary to Azure OpenAI endpoint...

The API deployment for this resource does not exist. If you created the deployment within the last 5 minutes, please wait a moment and try again.
dsur [ ~/azure-openai/Labfiles/02-nlp-azure-openai/Python ]$
```

**I have done this several times but still having trouble getting the code to see the endpoint. Not sure how to diagnose further the networking issues if that is the root problem. Any constructive suggestions would be greatly appreciated!**

Code:

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Add Azure OpenAI package
# Add OpenAI import
import openai

def main(): 
        
    try: 
    
        # Get configuration settings 
        load_dotenv()
        azure_oai_endpoint = os.getenv("AZURE_OAI_ENDPOINT")
        azure_oai_key = os.getenv("AZURE_OAI_KEY")
        azure_oai_model = os.getenv("AZURE_OAI_MODEL")
        
        # Read text from file
        text = open(file="../text-files/sample-text.txt", encoding="utf8").read()
        
        # Add code to build request...
        # Set OpenAI configuration settings
        openai.api_type = "azure"
        openai.api_base = azure_oai_endpoint
        openai.api_version = "2023-03-15-preview"
        openai.api_key = azure_oai_key

        # Send request to Azure OpenAI model
        print("Sending request for summary to Azure OpenAI endpoint...\n\n")
        response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            engine=azure_oai_model,
            temperature=0.7,
            max_tokens=120,
            messages=[
            {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant. Summarize the following text in 60 words or less."},
                {"role": "user", "content": text}
            ]
        )

        print("Summary: " + response.choices[0].message.content + "\n")

    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

I have tried several times in 2 different Azure subscriptons. When I create the openai resource all seems to go well. I feel its a networking or configuration issue of some sort.  Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine.

The error because of the name your are passing.

```
AZURE_OAI_MODEL=gpt-35-turbo
```

Need to give deployment name not model name.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That fixed it! The original instructions didn't indicate to fill out the AZURE_OAI_MODEL variable. I was guessing.  It's all good now.